# Laravel 5.1 Localize Factory Seeder

Tags: php, database, laravel

I implemented a new factory to generate random data. But I want to have this random data in the format of de_DE. So usually I create a faker object first, but this is not the case in Laravel 5.1 with the new ModelFactory class. How do I localize this then?

```
$factory->define(App\Models\AED::class, function($faker) {
    return [
        'owner' => $faker->company,
        'street' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'latitude' => $faker->latitude,
        'longitude' => $faker->longitude
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to change the default locale used by Faker, the easiest way is to simply override the `FakerGenerator` binding with your own concrete implementation:

```
// AppServiceProvider.php
$this->app->singleton(FakerGenerator::class, function () {
    return FakerFactory::create('nl_NL');
});
```

On top of your `AppServiceProvider.php` file add the following lines:

```
use Faker\Generator as FakerGenerator;
use Faker\Factory as FakerFactory;
```

For example, the above code will mean all Faker instances are created using the `nl_NL` provider, thus creating Dutch faker data.

Remember: this has to happen *after* the DatabaseServiceProvider has been executed, so make sure to put your own `AppServiceProvider` *after* all of the Laravel ServiceProviders in your `config.php` array.

Comment: This should have been the right answer to this problem. Laravel has loose component that must be defined before creation in order to not lose performance creating garbage objects. Only a note. include the path aliases like `Faker\Factory as FakerFactory` and `Faker\Generator as FakerGenerator` in order to this example to work

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$factory->define(App\Models\AED::class, function($faker) {
    $faker->locale = "YOUR_LOCALE";
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is another way to mid-fix the problem as you might (or should) need to include this line of code inside every definition. The Service Provider approach explained by @max is a better solution

Comment: @alwinKesler Indeed. It's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this either at the top of your ModelFactory.php or in your AppServiceProvider::register() method:

```
$this->app->singleton(\Faker\Generator::class, function () {
    return \Faker\Factory::create('de_DE');
});
```

Comment: Adding to ModelFactory did not work but AppServiceProvider::register() worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must add Providers eg.

```
$factory->define(Mylead\Models\UserDetails::class, function($faker) {

    $faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\pl_PL\Person($faker));
    $faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\pl_PL\Payment($faker));

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'surname' => $faker->lastname,
        'street' => $faker->streetName,
        'city' => $faker->city,
        'post_code' => $faker->pesel,
        'pesel' => $faker->pesel,
        'paypal' => $faker->email,
        'bank_name' => $faker->bank,
        'bank_account' => $faker->bankAccountNumber,
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime
    ];
});
```

For now You can't set manualy Faker locale. It should be changed on Laravel Core

Comment: how and where should this be changed on Laravel Core?

Comment: These 2 files:

`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::raw`

`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::__construct`

Comment: So, if you have 20 definitions, are you suggesting to include N providers in every one of them? This shouldn't be the way to proceed. Check out @max answer